# Yii cgridview add custom html attribute to buttons from data not working

Tags: php, yii

I tried to add custom html attribute to **cgridview** buttons  from **dataProvider** , Im using bootstrap yii bootstrap **bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn**

I tried

```
'pbs_id'=>'{$data->pbs_id}',
```

and

```
'pbs_id'=>'{$data["psp_id"]}',
```

but it return it as string

```
 $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
        'type'=>'striped bordered condensed',
        'dataProvider'=>$db_slabs_data,
        'template'=>"{items}",
        'columns'=>array(
            array('name'=> 'pbs_id', 'header'=>'Slab Id'),
            array('name'=> 'pbs_name',   'header'=>'Slab Name'),
            array(
                'htmlOptions' => array('nowrap'=>'nowrap'),
                'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
                'template'=>"{update}",
                'updateButtonUrl'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("", array("pbs_id"=>$data["pbs_id"]))',
                'buttons'=>array
                (   
                    'update' => array
                    (
                        'label'=> Yii::t('common', 'LBL_UPDATE'),
                        'icon'=>'icon-pencil',
                        'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("", array("pbs_id"=>$data["pbs_id"]))',
                        'options'=>array(
                            'pbs_id'=>'{$data["psp_id"]}',
                        ),
                    ),

                ),

            ),
        ),
    ));
```

ad the result is :

```
<a href="" pbs_id=1" rel="tooltip" title="" pbs_id="{$data-&gt;pbs_id}" data-original-title="Update"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>
```

how I can do that.

Thanks

Comment: did you try `'pbs_id'=>'$data->pbs_id',` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by:

inside this file **/protected/extensions/bootstrap/widgets/TbButtonColumn.php** there are a method `renderButton()`

I override this method to to render additional html attribute for buttons:

```
protected function renderButton($id, $button, $row, $data) {
        if (isset($button['visible']) && !$this->evaluateExpression($button['visible'], array('row' => $row, 'data' => $data)))
            return;

        $label = isset($button['label']) ? $button['label'] : $id;
        $url = isset($button['url']) ? $this->evaluateExpression($button['url'], array('data' => $data, 'row' => $row)) : '#';
        $options = isset($button['options']) ? $button['options'] : array();

        /* added to render additional html attribute */
        if (isset($button['options']) AND !(empty($button['options']))) {
            foreach ($button['options'] as $key => $value) {
                if (preg_match('#\$(data|row)#', $value)) {
                    $options["$key"] = $this->evaluateExpression($button['options'][$key], array('data' => $data, 'row' => $row));
                } else {
                    $options["$key"] = $value;
                }
            }
        }

        /* end */

        if (!isset($options['title']))
            $options['title'] = $label;

        if (!isset($options['rel']))
            $options['rel'] = 'tooltip';

        if (isset($button['icon'])) {
            if (strpos($button['icon'], 'icon') === false)
                $button['icon'] = 'icon-' . implode(' icon-', explode(' ', $button['icon']));

            echo CHtml::link('<i class="' . $button['icon'] . '"></i>', $url, $options);
        }
        else if (isset($button['imageUrl']) && is_string($button['imageUrl']))
            echo CHtml::link(CHtml::image($button['imageUrl'], $label), $url, $options);
        else
            echo CHtml::link($label, $url, $options);
    }
```

and inside the grid

```
'buttons'=>array
                (   
                    'update' => array
                    (
                        'label'=> Yii::t('common', 'LBL_UPDATE'),
                        'icon'=>'icon-pencil',
                        'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("", array("pbs_id"=>$data["pbs_id"]))',
                        'options'=>array(
                            'id'=>'$data["id"]',
                            'new_attribute'=> '$data["your_key"]',
                        ),
                    ),

                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you simply cannot do this like this, `options` values will not be evaluated as PHP expression : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CButtonColumn#buttons-detail

You should extend `bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn` to handle this, e.g. :

Create a new file `MyTbButtonColumn.php` in `protected/widgets` (or else) :

```
Yii::import('bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn');

class MyTbButtonColumn extends TbButtonColumn
{
    protected function renderButton($id, $button, $row, $data)
    {
        if (isset($button['options']) && is_array($button['options']))
        {
            foreach ($button['options'] as &$v)
            {
                // evaluate ?
                if (preg_match('#\$(data|row)#', $v))
                    $v = $this->evaluateExpression($v, array('data'=>$data, 'row'=>$row));
            }
        }
        parent::renderButton($id, $button, $row, $data);
    }
}
```

And modify your view :

```
$this->widget('application.widgets.MyTbButtonColumn', array(...));
```

PS: You could also use javascript to add these attributes.